# How do I replace only the current instance of the search pattern without losing the pattern?

Tags: search, replace

I often find myself doing an interactive search and replace for a string that may be either a whole word *or* a partial word, such as changing `bar` to `jaz` and also `foo_bar_blah` to `foo_jaz_blah`.

So I can't just do `cw`.  But if I do for example `c/_<CR>` then I've lost `bar` as the search pattern.  How can I change just the current instance of the search pattern and retain that search pattern?

Comment: `c/_<cr>` is perhaps better written `ct_`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the current match (or next match, if the cursor is not on a match) use `cgn` or `gnc`.  Alone, `gn` visually selects the match.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer I finally found after sifting through the vimdoc site, specifically [the chapter on patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) scrolling a few paragraphs below the section labeled `*search-offset*`

```
An example of how to search for matches with a pattern and change the match
with another word:
    /foo<CR>    find "foo"
    c//e        change until end of match
    bar<Esc>    type replacement
    //<CR>      go to start of next match
    c//e        change until end of match
    beep<Esc>   type another replacement
                etc.
```

The important thing is NOT to use `n` to move to the next instance, because doing so will put you at the END of that instance.  You must use `//<CR>` as shown.  You can use `.` as usual if you just want to repeat the previous `c//e` change.